# Asus z8na mother board. Do the two cpus need to be the same?

Tags: hardware, asus

I have a asus z8na motherboard, with one E5504 cpu atm. Can i put an E5506 next to it or should the two cpus be identical?

Comment: Normally you always need the same CPUs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both CPU's should be identical.

Comment: Identical in both model and stepping.

Comment: Thanks, i will have to look into the stepping thing. Also, i dont think i can find the same ram bloks as im using with the current cpu. Do i need to buy all new ram bloks for both cpus, or do it only need same type for each cpu parts.